# Problem with Humanoid_Navigation in Indigo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, I occured a problem during the installation of Humanoid_Navigation package. Following this guide http://wiki.ros.org/humanoid_navigation?distro=hydro when I do "catkin_make", something goes wrong:

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'humanoid_planner_2d'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(humanoid_navigation/humanoid_planner_2d)
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26")
-- checking for module 'sbpl'
--   package 'sbpl' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
humanoid_navigation/humanoid_planner_2d/CMakeLists.txt:10 (pkg_check_modules)

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'footstep_planner'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(humanoid_navigation/footstep_planner)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genjava;genlisp;genpy
-- checking for module 'sbpl'
--   package 'sbpl' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
humanoid_navigation/footstep_planner/CMakeLists.txt:10 (pkg_check_modules)

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'humanoid_localization'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genjava;genlisp;genpy
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Found OpenMP: -fopenmp
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   random
CMake Error at humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
By not providing "FindEigen.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen" with any of
the following names:

```
EigenConfig.cmake
eigen-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "Eigen" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Eigen_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Can someone help me?
Thanks to all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227554/problem-with-humanoid_navigation-in-indigo/) by [kalum](https://answers.ros.org/users/26067/kalum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't have EigenConfig.cmake. Try getting cmake_modules (http://wiki.ros.org/cmake_modules).

---

Originally posted by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) with karma: 194 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0